# in function def, multi clauses start with common match

Tags: elixir

[The following codes from `nx` project, `nx/nx/type.ex` file.](https://github.com/elixir-nx/nx/blob/main/nx/lib/nx/type.ex)

Why the first line exist, it has no function body and the condition is always match? I can't find related elixir reference doc.

```
def infinity_binary(type)
  def infinity_binary({:bf, 16}), do: <<0x7F80::16-native>>
  def infinity_binary({:f, 16}), do: <<0x7C00::16-native>>
  def infinity_binary({:f, 32}), do: <<0x7F800000::32-native>>
  def infinity_binary({:f, 64}), do: <<0x7FF0000000000000::64-native>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done for documentation purpose, in order to have better argument names.

As you can see on [hexdocs](https://hexdocs.pm/nx/0.2.1/Nx.Type.html#infinity_binary/1), ex_doc is able to use this name instead of relying on a default sub-optimal naming such as `tuple`.

The reference can be found [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/writing-documentation.html#function-arguments).

Comment: It’s worth adding that function heads are most commonly used to allow default values for arguments for multi-claused functions.